Cultivation manhwa/manhua where the main character is poor and his father is a blacksmith
I think its main character is reincarnated but not confirmed. The main character is born in a Murim world. He has two brothers. They are a poor family and his father is a blacksmith (not so good).
He became rich after mass production of something using the blacksmith. He also became very strong in Murim after some time.
He created delivery and other modern inventions and became very rich.

Are there any SF&F aspects to this?

@Chenmunka Murim and Cultivation are both specific fantasy terms. Murim is an alternate martial arts focused world; cultivation I'm less clear on but it's something like gaining spiritual powers with the goal of obtaining immortality.

This is "A modern man who transmigrated into the murim world".
His father is blacksmith, so he introduces business model based on Apple company's iphone and factory production for producing ploughs - employ a lot of people, specialize them, then sell product with good renown and so on.
He finds cave with writings of ultimate martial art written with algebraic expressions.
